# How to replace values in all columns in Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I know how to replace values in specific columns value.
Following example is how to replace value '[NULL]' to blank in 'col01'.

```
df['col01'] = df['col01'].str.replace('[NULL]', '')
```

However I have no idea to replace value without column names.
I would like to make all columns as a replacement targets.

How can I make a code? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you need [`DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
df = df.replace('[NULL]', '')
```

If need replace substrings:

```
df = df.replace('\[NULL\]', '', regex=True)
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['[NULL]','f','[NULL] aa'],
                   'b':['w','[NULL]','d [NULL]']})

print(df)
           a         b
0     [NULL]         w
1          f    [NULL]
2  [NULL] aa  d [NULL]

df1 = df.replace('[NULL]', '')
print (df1)
           a         b
0                    w
1          f          
2  [NULL] aa  d [NULL]

df2 = df.replace('\[NULL\]', '', regex=True)
print (df2)
     a   b
0        w
1    f    
2   aa  d
```